# XAMPP only allow specific LAN device access

Tags: networking, xampp, lan

I'm looking to allow a specific device (in this case one particular iPad) access to XAMPP on a computer on the same LAN. I don't want any other devices besides this one and the server itself to be able to access localhost or anything else though. I'm able to find ways to enable LAN access online but to my understanding this could allow anyone on the same network to access XAMPP if they have the server's IP.

Comment: Find your iPAD mac address and see: https://serverfault.com/questions/519480/iptables-allow-access-from-certain-mac-addresses . Note that using iptables will block other devices but it's not reallly secure and a malicious code can forge requests with your mac address

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about the apache server inside xampp, you can use this kind of solution: https://serverfault.com/questions/776252/allow-access-to-apache-server-from-only-one-ip-address

Similar solution can be found for the integrated tomcat, MySQL, etc...

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using Apache 2.4**, make sure that you LOAD the authz_core module,

DELETE:

```
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
Allow from my.ip.add.res
and, in place of the deleted directives,
```

INSERT:

```
Require ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
**If you are using Apache 2.2**, make sure that you LOAD the authz_host module,
```

DELETE:

```
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
Allow from my.ip.add.res
and, in place of the deleted directives,
```

INSERT:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Comment: Reposted answer. Original post: https://serverfault.com/questions/776252/allow-access-to-apache-server-from-only-one-ip-address

Answer (score 0):

It is slightly off-topic to what's being requested, but requesting credentials is a simple, effective way to restrict access without worrying about IP addresses or MAC addresses.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication

e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44560458/3196753

This may not fulfill certain security requirements (e.g. HIPAA, PCI) but for simply keeping unauthorized people out, it is tremendously simple and effective.